# How to make Laravel Livewire scripts work with other JS scripts?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Laravel Livewire scripts(129 row) doesn't work with other js-scripts(117,118 rows)

I assume that Livewire doesn't work with scripts as it uses asynchronous script loading, which may appear to be errors when initializing Livewire, so I tried to add defer or async and nothing helped.

What can I do to run all these scripts?

[image]

I tried to add defer or async and nothing helped.

Comment: What if you add the scripts inside the livewire view?

Comment: I tried, didn't work

Comment: Without knowing what the scripts are, what they do and what isn't working it's hard to say what is the problem. Does the browser console say anything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.